# Why do BIM 360 viewer models occasionally tell me I don't have the required privileges to access the item?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I'm working on making a program to view 3D models that I upload to BIM 360 using document management APIs. Everything worked just fine but when I went to go test it out for most of the models, but I discovered that some of the models give me a message saying "No Access. Sorry. You don't have the required privileges to access this item. Please contact author" when viewing in our viewer API. This only happens to specific models and so far the only fix I found was opening it through the BIM 360 website, which after that allows me to successfully open it in my viewer API. The only issue is that I need to be able to open it from my end without opening it through BIM 360.

This is what I have for my script.

```
var viewer;
    var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
        api: 'streamingV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'streamingV2_EU'
        getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
            var token = [access token];
            var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by APS Authentication (OAuth) API
            onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
                }
            };Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {

    var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
    var startedCode = viewer.start();
            if (startedCode > 0) {
            console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
            return;
            }

        console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');

            });var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv, {});

    var documentId = [document urn];
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);

    function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
    // viewerDocument is an instance of Autodesk.Viewing.Document
    var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
        viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
        }

    function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
            console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
    }
```

Comment: The working way you mentioned is the behavior if the models with Autodesk260, Fusion360. As to BIM360 or ACC, the model will be translated automatically after it is uploaded to Filed module. The metadata should be viewable by default.

Comment: Two questions: 1.  what are the format of those models?   2.  if you use 3-legged token in your application, are those models in the same folder with other models( that can be viewed without problem) ?

Comment: @XiaodongLiang I am uploading NWC files to BIM 360, where they undergo automatic translation to SVF format. To answer your second question, I am using 2-legged tokens.

Comment: Sorry for my late response.  With the information you provided, it is weird that some models ask for privilege  occasionally. Could you book a time with our team to diagnose remotely? https://calendly.com/autodesk-platform-services